# Before hockey, did the word “puck” exist?

Tags: etymology, sports

I was trying to search history on the word *puck*, but couldn’t find what I was looking for. It seems that before 1870 there were only ever instances of “puck” when used as a name. Some sources, like Etymonline, indicate it originated from “[poke](https://www.etymonline.com/word/puck)”, which referred to the hitting or striking of the object. I was wondering if there were any other potential sources of this word, as we often refer to other similarly shaped objects as “pucks”.

Comment: Note that "Puck" (as used by Shakey & others) was a "sprite" (a sort of fairy) and it's not unlikely that the hockey "puck" drew on that meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks Why do you say that? Except for the form of the word itself (and perhaps the fact that both are small), I don't see any real connection between them.

Comment: The full OED says the *noun* puck (a disc, first recorded 1886) derives from the *verb* *(**transitive. To hit or strike; to butt; to box**)*. First citation 1861 - *The ball was struck here and there, often **pucked** up in the air, then let again before it reached the ground.* The OED says the origin is probably Irish, but they don't say exactly how it arose, apart from suggesting that the 1641 citation *Hee also would to the threshing of the cock, pucke with hens, blindfold, and the like* probably ***isn't*** relevant, even though some scholars have obviously tried to big that one up.

Answer (score 5):

The OED's first example of the word "puck" in the modern sense comes from the *Boston Daily Globe* in 1866:

> In hockey a flat piece of rubber, say four inches long by three wide
>   and about an inch thick, called a ‘puck’, is used.

There's a much older definition of the word:

> An evil, malicious, or mischievous spirit or demon of popular belief.

The OED has examples of this definition going back to 1378. According to the etymology, this meaning is even older:

> Probably cognate with Old Icelandic púki mischievous demon, the Devil

You are correct in thinking that the use of the name "puck" for the small rubber disc likely came from the verb "poke." Around the same time that the black biscuit got its name, the verb "to puck" had been developed as an offshoot of "to poke." Here's how the OED defines that infinitive version of "puck":

> To hit or strike; to butt; to box.

Comment: Postscript: I can't imagine passing or shooting a non-circular puck. Before writing this post, I assumed that pucks had always been perfect circles.

Answer (score 2):

This probably comes from the Irish "poc" meaning to stroke a ball (pronounced puck), from the game of hurling it would have travelled into Hockey through the Irish in North America.  Interesting it is now being used for dongles connected to TVs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is actually the most likely etymology. The word has a very similar meaning in a very similar game (for those who don’t know, hurling is a kind of aerial field hockey) played by a population who first came to North America in large numbers right before the word “puck” first appeared in writing. Here’s the Irish definition: https://www.teanglann.ie/en/fgb/puck